# What's standard behavior when <button> element is clicked? Will it submit the form?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

What is the standard behavior for when a `<button>` element is clicked in a form? Will it submit the form?

Question is about tag/element `<button>`, not `<input type=button>`.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

If the button is within a form, the default behavior is submit.

If the button is not within a form, it will do nothing.

BUT BE AWARE!

> Always specify the type attribute for
>   the button. The default type for
>   Internet Explorer is "button", while
>   in other browsers (and in the W3C
>   specification) it is "submit".

Taken from  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp

Comment: `button` with no `type` attribute is submitting in IE11.

Comment: I can't believe I'm saying this, but I think IE has it right, while everyone else is wrong.
I think I just threw up a little.
I see that w3 says the default should be `submit`, but logically, `button` makes more sense.

Answer (score 22):

Yes it default to the `submit` type.

> type = submit|button|reset [CI]
>      This attribute declares the type of the button. Possible values:
>
> `submit`: Creates a submit button. This is **the default value**.

See: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5

So when the `button` is inside a form it will submit it, when it's not inside a form, it still defaults to `submit` but does nothing (since there's no form associated with it).

As raRaRa has pointed out below older versions of IE have the `button` tag default type set to `button`:  http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/button-wont-submit-in-ie