# When any button click form will auto submit even the button is a different function

Tags: javascript, html, forms

All the button in the form, submit the form automatically, but I need other button function.

Code here:

```
     <html lang="en">
     <title>NTF Catering Service</title>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
      <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">              </script> 
       <script src="js/js.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
   <body>
       <form action="create.php" method="post">

         <select multiple="multiple" class="options" id="textarea">
         <option value="item1">Item 1</option>
         <option value="item2">Item 2</option>
         <option value="item3">Item 3</option>
         <option value="item4">Item 4</option>
          <option value="item5">Item 5</option>
        </select>


    <button id="copy">Copy</button>
    <button id="remove">Remove</button>

     <select id="textarea2" multiple class="remove">


<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
    </select>
     </html>
```

Comment: Change your code first your submit button and form closing is now inside your <select> tag

Answer (score 2):

If you mean that all  the Buttons submit your form then add the following to the  elements: **type="button"**

```
<button type="button" id="copy">Copy</button>
<button type="button" id="remove">Remove</button>
```

This should ensure only the  will submit the form

Then control these via your jquery code:

```
    $('#copy').on('click', function(e){ ///do stuff here });
    $('#remove').on('click', function(e){ ///do stuff here });
```

or add onclick to the buttons:

```
<button onclick="someCopyfunction();" type="button" id="copy">Copy</button>
<button onclick="someRemovefunction();"  type="button" id="remove">Remove</button>
```

etc

Comment: tnx for your reply, but i need other buttons function because <button id="copy">COPY</button> and <button id="remove">Remove</button> is other function a jquery of 1textbox submited to another textbox. but i need also the <input type="submit" name="submit" /> for the textarea to submit to database

Comment: then in jquery you control them as in $('#copy').on('click',function(e){}) etc

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged jQuery and Javascript you can also use:

```
$('input[name="submit"]').click(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  //Do other stuff here
});
```

Comment: I dont see the `jQuery` tag in the Question

Comment: The tag has been removed in an edit: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21281503/revisions

Answer (score 1):

By default `<button>` tags are submit button , to make them just button use

```
<button type="button">copy</button>
<button type="button">Remove</button>
```

Check this [what's the standard behavior when < button > tag click? will it submit the form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667979/whats-the-standard-behavior-when-button-tag-click-will-it-submit-the-form)

**Note** Always specify the type attribute for a `<button>` element. Different browsers use different default types for the  element.

Use `<input>` to create buttons in an HTML form.

Comment: Ya I accept some one pointed out the mistakes in your code I just wanted to help to understand more about how and when buttons are used and how do they function.

Answer (score 0):

Now you are write input button inside `<select>` tag.

```
 <select id="textarea2" multiple class="remove">    

   <input type="submit" name="submit" />
   </form>
    </select>
```

To

```
</select>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" />
 </form>
```

**Also**
If you don't want to submit your button

Change

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
```

**TO**

```
<input type="button" name="submit" onclick='yourFunction()' />
```

Comment: is this same try it tnx for your reply same as simon Davies

Comment: If you want to submit it add `form.submit` inside your script that is inside `yourFunction()`

Comment: OW ok it run tnx for your help:))) guys

Answer (score -1):

Try these one if it may work for you

```
<form action="">
  <textarea value="text here..." type="submit" method="post"></textarea>
</form>
```