# Form with multiple buttons - all are submitting the form

Tags: jquery

My form, 'file-upload' has a submit button:

```
<button id="btn-save" type="submit">Save</button>
```

I use it like so:

```
$('#file-upload').submit(this.save.bind(this));
```

The problem is, my form has other buttons in it:

```
<button class="btn-delete">&times;</button>
```

And these appear to be running the this.save method.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [what's the standard behavior when < button > tag click? will it submit the form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667979/whats-the-standard-behavior-when-button-tag-click-will-it-submit-the-form)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a know behavior, all `<button>` s inside the form tag would act like a submit button, you either need to prevent its default behavior by `event.preventDefault()` or change those buttons to `<input type='button'>`

Comment: You can also add type="button" to the button element: 

<button type="button" class="btn-delete">&times;</button>

If you prefer not to change them to inputs.