# What is the default button type?

Tags: html, button

If I do this:

```
<button name="Save">Save</button>
```

can I be assured that it will behave the same way across all browsers?

Comment: @SachinNambiarNalavattanon No, that other question is about `<input`, not about `<button`. And it asks something entirely else.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

For most browsers the default `type` of `button` is `submit`.

> **type = submit|button|reset [CI]**
>
> This attribute declares the type of the button. Possible values:
>
> submit: Creates a submit button. This is the default value.

(http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5)

The only exception to this is IE7 and below where the default `type` is `button`.

> Windows Internet Explorer 8 and later. The default value of this attribute depends on the current document compatibility mode. In IE8 Standards mode, the default value is submit. In other compatibility modes and earlier versions of Windows Internet Explorer, the default value is button.

(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534696(v=vs.85).aspx)

If old IE support is not an issue (older versions of IE also have trouble with multiple `button`s on one `form` and the text of the`button` being passed through instead of the`value`) you can probably get away with not supplying the `type` attribute for a `button`.

Comment: Is it only me thinking that defaulting `type` to `submit` is freakin' dumb?

Comment: I think the default value of `type` property should be set to `button` !!!

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know the default is `"submit"` except for IE which default is `"button"`

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4667996/3080244) for more details

---

**Edit**

According to the Microsoft Developer Network [specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535211(v=vs.85).aspx):

> In IE8 Standards mode, the default value is submit. In other
>   compatibility modes and earlier versions of Windows Internet Explorer,
>   the default value is button.

Comment: I wonder what version of IE switched from type="button" to type="submit"?

Answer (score 1):

The input button maybe looks different in the browsers but the function of the input will be the same.
check: [button ,W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html)