# Form button, without type submit, submits form

Tags: html, forms, button, submit

I know that type="submit" on a button, it's the same as an input.

The question here is: if I have a form, without any submit button/input, why is it triggering the submit?

```
<form method="post" action="lf-p1-02a.html">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center flex-wrap buttonCheck multiButtonCheck">
        <button class="col-md-6 formButton bigButton">
            <span>Button 1</span>
        </button>
        <button class="col-md-6 formButton bigButton">
            <span>Button 2</span>
        </button>
        <button class="col-md-6 formButton bigButton">
            <span>Button 3</span>
        </button>
        <button class="col-md-6 formButton bigButton">
            <span>Button 4</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center formFooter">
        <button class="mainBtn">Continue</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/36zsa1t8/ (I know that there aren't any styles).

The Continue button from the form is actually submitting it, going to the next page.

No JavaScript on the code.

Any idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31644723/what-is-the-default-button-type), For most browsers the default `type` of `button` is `submit`.

Comment: Thanks for that, I would not realized that. Nice to know more!

Answer (score 1):

Change `<Button>` tag to `<input type="button" value="Button">`

```
<input type="button" class="col-md-6 formButton bigButton" value="Button">
            <span>Utilizo el listado mensual de<br> consumo o límite preconcedido</span>
        </input>
```

Updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36zsa1t8/2/)