# Why a second Bootstrap 3 Button (not marked as 'submit') is submitting my form?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, form-submit

My Bootstrap 3 edit form had initially only a Submit button that worked perfectly.  When I added another button to implement a 'Cancel' option, it didn't work as expected, and a click on it is submitting the form (and saving changes). Of course I didn't mark this second button as 'Submit', not being intended for that.

My HTML/PHP code looks like this:

```
<form method='POST' action='savechanges.php'>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="IdDataList">List Id</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="IdDataList" readonly value="<?php echo $row['IdDataList']; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="DataListName">List Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="DataListName" name="DataListName" value="<?php echo $row['DataListName']; ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="DataListDescription">Description</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="DataListDescription" name="DataListDescription" value="<?php echo $row['DataListDescription']; ?>">
    </div>

<!-- Submit button -->
    <div class="form-group col-sm">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" name="saveall" type="submit" >Save changes</button>
    </div>

<!-- Here the second 'Cancel' button -->
    <div class="form-group col-sm">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" name="goback" onclick="window.location.href='anotherpage.php'">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Must be something obvious but I can't see what's going wrong...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: if button is causing the issue you can give the button type as `type="button"` or use `a` tag their. you can check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31644723/what-is-the-default-button-type as default button type is submit

Comment: Thanks, @Chilll007 that was the problem, similar question found here too:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932653/how-to-prevent-buttons-from-submitting-forms   Most browsers use 'submit' if the type is not specified.

Comment: glad to know that it solves the issue :)

Answer (score -1):

Credit for this answer goes to @Chilll007, as I decided to close this question myself.
The current HTML standard, as adopted by most browsers, states that the **type** attribute should be used to differentiate the button's behavior, defaulting to 'submit' type.

Buttons that don't serve to this purpose should be marked as generic with **type='button'**.  To get hyperlink behavior you can define actions through Javascript or with an `<a href=''></a>` tag:

```
<a href="anotherpage.php"class="btn btn-primary" name="back" role="button">Cancel</a>
```

Comment: `a` tags **cannot have interactive children** like `button` or `label`. The HTML you suggest is invalid.

Comment: Absolutely right! I must have pasted that code from another answer (and that worked :), I corrected the code as suggested.