# JavaScript - Having Trouble With eventListener Method

Tags: javascript, html, forms, addeventlistener

I am working with html forms and adding functionality to buttons using JS. I have created a  to capture the user's name once this ones is introduced in the text field. The problem is that when I try to display the user's input on the console, this one appears for a very short instant and then disappears. `

The following is my HTML code:

```
    <form action="">
        <div>
            <label for="myName">Name</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="myName" id="myName" class="name">
        </div>
            <button class="thisOne">Collect Info</button>

    </form>`
```

The next one is my JS

```
` let input_name = document.querySelector('.name');
     let btn = document.querySelector('button');
     btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{   
     console.log(input_name.value);
      });`
```

Comment: `<button>`s have a default type of "submit", see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31644856/2610061). For this reason they will submit the form and divert you to the URL given in its action attribute.

Comment: Set your button type to "button". I know it sounds redundant but gives you a button with no actions attached to it (such as submit).

Comment: Phaelax z, you mean adding a <input type='button'>
I wasn't aware that <button> had that kind of confusing way of behaving. Well, I am a bigginer, so not quite sure how everything works/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use event, and preventDefault, to prevent sending the form.

```js
const input_name = document.querySelector('.name');

const btn = document.querySelector('.thisOne');

btn.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(input_name.value);
});
```

```html
<form action="">
  <div>
      <label for="myName">Name</label>
  </div>
  <div>
      <input type="text" name="myName" id="myName" class="name">
  </div>
      <button class="thisOne">Collect Info</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Wow!!! exphoenee, thank you very very much!!!!