# React Component getting displayed and disappearing immediately

Tags: reactjs, components

I'm learning React and as part of that I have tried some code for making a notebook kind of app where I get to add notes and then they are displayed dynamically

When I'm trying to add a note, the new react component(note) is getting displayed but immediately getting disappeared. As if the entire browser is refreshed. Attaching my code. This is my first time asking the question so not even sure how of it was understandable.

https://codesandbox.io/s/keeper-part-3-starting-forked-0mf1cs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For most of the modern browsers the default `type` of `button` tag is `submit` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/31644856/7399478). So, the form is submitted when you click the button and the page is refreshed after submit.

You need to change add `type="button"` to your `button` tag in your `CreateArea.jsx` component in order to prevent submitting the form like:

```
<button
  type="button"
  onClick={() => {
    props.onAdd(note);
  }}
>
  Add
</button>
```

Comment: Thank you ...it really helped.....i went with other way where i used preventDefault and added that to my form element through callback function....but your answer was much simple and easy...