# Angular Material Hide Password toggles on enter

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I'm new to angular and i have a project that already has a login with a username and password input. The password input has a button to show the password. The problem is, that when im in the password input field and i press enter, it toggles the button to show the password instead of submitting the form. How can i change that?

### component.html

```
<div style="text-align: center" class="centered">
  <form [formGroup]="form">
    <br>
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Username</mat-label>
      <input name="username" formControlName="username" matInput>
    </mat-form-field>
    <br>
    <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
      <input name="password" formControlName="password" matInput [type]="passwordVisible ? 'text' : 'password'">
      <button mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="passwordVisible = !passwordVisible" [attr.aria-label]="'Hide password'"
              [attr.aria-pressed]="!passwordVisible">
        <mat-icon>{{passwordVisible ? 'visibility' : 'visibility_off'}}</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </mat-form-field>
    <br>
    <button (click)="login()" mat-raised-button>Login</button>
    <button (click)="navigateToRegister()" mat-raised-button color="primary" style="margin-left: 10px">Register</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Default type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31644856/5621827) for the `button` is `submit` that might be causing this issue try changing your show/hide button `type` to `button` something like

```
<button type="button" mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="passwordVisible = !passwordVisible" [attr.aria-label]="'Hide password'"
              [attr.aria-pressed]="!passwordVisible">
        <mat-icon>{{passwordVisible ? 'visibility' : 'visibility_off'}}</mat-icon>
      </button>
```

Answer (score 2):

I also stumbled upon this issue recently and was able to resolve it using the approach below.

Method `onClickRevealPassword` will be called if you press enter on the password input field. Such action results in an event called `pointerType` which you can detect with this method and keep the password field not to reveal the plain password value. Have a look and experiment it with your component.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Password</mat-label>
  <input name="password" formControlName="password" matInput [type]="passwordVisible ? 'text' : 'password'">
  <button mat-icon-button matSuffix (click)="passwordVisible = !passwordVisible; onClickRevealPassword($event)" [attr.aria-label]="'Hide password'"
          [attr.aria-pressed]="!passwordVisible">
    <mat-icon>{{passwordVisible ? 'visibility' : 'visibility_off'}}</mat-icon>
  </button>
</mat-form-field>

onClickRevealPassword(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // Prevent revealing the password when enter button is pressed.
  if (event?.pointerType) {
    this.passwordVisible = !this.passwordVisible;
  }
}
```