# JQuery .clone() isn't working when an html5 form tag is present

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to build a cloning plugin and started with the simple example they used on W3C.  At first when I tried it I would see the data blink on the page and disappear.  I saw nothing wrong in the console, I played with it in JS fiddle and got an error telling me to use "post", so I added the a post method to the form tag and still got the same result.

However when I took away the form tag, the clone worked.  Does anybody understand why this would happen?

Here's the HTML

```
<body>
    <fieldset id="question01">
        <input type="text" id="ques_01_text" placeholder="text01" name="ques_01" />
        <input type="text" id="ques_02_text" placeholder="text02" name="ques_02" />
        <input type="text" id="ques_03_text" placeholder="text03" name="ques_03" />
    </fieldset>

    <button>add</button>
</body>
```

Here's the Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $("#question01").clone().appendTo("body");
    });
});
```

Comment: I guess, when the button is clicked, form is submitted. so, it doesn't seem to work

Comment: hi dear  it's working fine see here http://jsfiddle.net/gxtm6sw4/

Answer (score 0):

when you have a button in a form, it acts as a `submit` button by default. That is to say, when you have this:

```
<button>add</button>
```

It actually gets interpreted as this:

```
<button type='submit'>add</button>
```

See here for more info: [what's the standard behavior when < button > tag click? will it submit the form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667979/whats-the-standard-behavior-when-button-tag-click-will-it-submit-the-form)

So when you click it, regardless of your click event, it still submits the form, which you don't want. That explains why it works when you don't have a form; there is nothing to submit, so it's submit action is inert. To make the button **not** submit, you can just change its type to `button`

```
<button type='button'>add</button>
```

And then when it is inside a form, it won't automatically submit when you click it.

Answer (score 0):

Your form was submitting. If you don't want you form to submit specify that the button is just a "button" and not a "submit button"... like so:

```
<button type="button">Add</button>
```

Rather than

```
<button type="submit">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$($('#question01').get(0).cloneNode(true)).appendTo('body')
```