# 2 buttons on form only 1 with submit type but both triggers submit event

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Not using jQuery, just plain javascript with DOM.
There are 2 buttons on the form, one has no type, one has type="submit"

Here is an example of my question:

https://plnkr.co/edit/wAlpawx2wJUZ9FXWXL9h?p=preview

```
         <div>
            <button class="add">add</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit">submit</button>
        </div>
```

both buttons trigger the submit event. how do I get only the button with type="submit" to trigger the submit event?

Also, how do I persist the form data so that the result can stay in the "pre" tag when the submit is triggered?

Comment: Buttons by default inside of a form trigger the submit. For the second button (that you don't want to submit) you need to prevent the default action from occurring, which is to submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set the type attribute to "button" or manually cancel the event

```
<button type='button' class='add'>add</button>
```

-or-

```
$('button.add').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // cancel default behavior
    // my add logic
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The default type of a `button` inside a form is  `submit`. You need to set `type="button"` if you want to prevent it from triggering the form submit.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667979/whats-the-standard-behavior-when-button-tag-click-will-it-submit-the-form) question for more details.

Answer (score 2):

you only need to change the type of the button that you don't want to submit with "button". I know it feels weird, but the default type of a button tag is "submit".

```
<button type="button">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

As per specifications:

> The missing value default is the Submit Button state.
>
> If the type attribute is in the Submit Button state, the element is specifically a submit button.

[W3C documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#attr-button-type)