# Javascript code is not working on putting html code inside 'form' tag. why?

Tags: html, asp.net

This is my code.

I have a aspx file. I have two JavaScript scripts in it. I have a css code also. I need to fade out the label on button click. It is working when I without use form tag and why not working on using form tag.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>

<style type="text/css">
    .notification
    {
        background-color:#006699;
        min-height:40px;
        width:30%;
        margin:0 auto;
        text-align:center;
        line-height:50px;
        color:#fff;
        font-size:18px;
        box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
    }
</style>


<script src="google.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".btn1").click(function () {
            $("#dvMsg").fadeOut(5000, 0, 0);
        });

    });
</script>

</head>
<body>     
<form id="form1">
   <div id="dvMsg" class="notification" runat="server" visible="true">
   <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" Text="This is just "></asp:Label>
   </div>  

   <button class="btn1">Fade out</button>
   </form>

</body>
</html>
```

If I remove form tag, label is fading out properly. But if I put html code inside `<form>` tag label is not fading out. Kindly reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667979/whats-the-standard-behavior-when-button-tag-click-will-it-submit-the-form) and in [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button), the default type for a button is `submit`, which behaves differently depending if the button is in a form or not. To avoid sumbitting the form and get the result that you expect, you should set the button type to `button`:

```
<button class="btn1" type="button">Fade out</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using latest version of Jquery try like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('.btn1').on("click", function () {
          $("#dvMsg").fadeOut(5000, 0, 0);
      });
});
```