# page reloads when using document.getElementById

Tags: javascript

Im using the js function shown below to make a part of page disappear when user clicks on the button.

but when i click on the button, the part does disappear, but then page reloads. 
why is it like this?

```
<button id="myDIV" onclick="fncShowHide()">Try it</button>

<script>
window.fncShowHide = function() {
   document.getElementById("idein").className = "display-none";
}
</script>
```

Comment: `<button type="button" id="myDIV" onclick="fncShowHide()">Try it</button>`

Comment: is the button in a form?

Comment: @leo — If ___NO___, won't it make us _quit_ the development..

Comment: @Rayon SIMPLE.. thanks a lot :) .. I don't know js :/

Comment: calm down guys.. i know it was a stupid mistake :)))

Comment: @kiasati — Comment was not for you man! So take it easy :)

Answer (score 4):

See [What's the standard behavior when < button > tag click?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4667996/2011448).

Return `false` from the `onclick` handler to prevent any default browser action.

```
<button id="myDIV" onclick="fncShowHide(); return false;">Try it</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

## ?

```js
window.fncShowHide = function() {
   document.getElementById("idein").className = "display-none";
}

window.other_ = function() {
   document.getElementById("idein").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.display-none{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<button id="myDIV" onclick="fncShowHide(); return false;">Try it</button>
<div id="idein">BYEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE!</div>
<script>

</script>
```