# button type reset not working for default values

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Hi This is my form...

```
<form id="frmer" class="form-inline" method="POST">
    <input name="inp1" value="sda"/>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr5">Search</button>
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default" form="frmer">Reset</button>
</form>
```

I want to clear this default value also from text input when I click the reset button. But unfortunately it wouldn't happen. If someone know how to archive it or any workaround it would be a great help..

Comment: @LuudJacobs — Why?

Comment: Depending on your usecase, I'd recommend using placeholder instead of a default value. To clear the fields, you will need to use js

Comment: Placeholder … or `<label>`, since the field doesn't have a `<label>` at the moment, that is probably the real solution.

Comment: We cannot reset the value in HTML for reset button.. You must have to use jquery or javascript yo reset the form.

Comment: @quentin, nevermind... brainfart

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reset means "reset" not "blank". It is *supposed* to restore the default values.

If you want to blank the form, then you'll need JavaScript.

Loop over each control and test what type it is. Ignore buttons. Set the values of text, search, number, etc fields to `""` (an empty string). Set the `checked` property of checkboxes to `false` and so on.

Comment: Quentin: a `<button>` inside a form will submit on default http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667979/whats-the-standard-behavior-when-button-tag-click-will-it-submit-the-form (Other answer got deleted, so I can't reply there).

Comment: @Roberrrt — By default, yes, but the HTML has `type="reset"` which overrides the default.