# Jquery: Loading some other URL on click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a project which includes some JQuery and AJAX. I have also implemented a feature of JQuery autofill. The code of form is shown below:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="polciynumber" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Please Enter Policy Number:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4 ui-widget">
            <input id="endtpolnumber" type="text" class="form-control col-sm-1" name="endtpolnumber" placeholder="Plase Enter Policy Number">
            <button id="findpolinfo" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-3">Find Policy</button>
        </div>
        <label for="insuredsname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Department:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="endtdept" name="endtdept" placeholder="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="addendt">Add Endorsement</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" id="addendtclearform">Clear Form</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The Autofill is implemented on the textbox with ID "endtpolnumber". When I click on textbox with ID "findpolinfo" it should alert "asdf". But, on contrary it is redirecting me to to this URL

"http://localhost/dis/home/login?endtpolnumber=31-125&endtefffrom=&endtno=&endtamt=&endtdesc="

My JQuery code is as below:

```
$('#findpolinfo').click(function () {
        alert('asdf');
    });
```

Does anyone have any idea, where am i going wrong?

All positive suggestions are welcomed...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: button default behaviour is submit unless you add type="button"

Comment: @JYoThI I added type="button", but still its not alerting anything

Answer (score 0):

Because the default behavoiur of `<button>` if it is inside form is submit

> [what's the standard behavior when < button > tag click? will it submit the form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667979/whats-the-standard-behavior-when-button-tag-click-will-it-submit-the-form)

add

```
type="button"
```

if you don't want this button to submit form

Comment: how can we override it? because I tried "e.preventDefault()", But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Button has a default behaviour to submit the form. You can use `return false` to stop that form submission. Below is code to help you out. Just enter the policy number and click on the 'Find Policy' button:

```js
$('#findpolinfo').click(function () {
        alert($("#endtpolnumber").val());
        return false;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="polciynumber" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Please Enter Policy Number:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4 ui-widget">
            <input id="endtpolnumber" type="text" class="form-control col-sm-1" name="endtpolnumber" placeholder="Plase Enter Policy Number">
            <button id="findpolinfo" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-3">Find Policy</button>
        </div>
        <label for="insuredsname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Department:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="endtdept" name="endtdept" placeholder="" disabled="disabled">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="addendt">Add Endorsement</button>
            <button class="btn btn-warning" id="addendtclearform">Clear Form</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

based on [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp) if you want to add button just for clicking,You can add `type="button"` to your `button` attributes.just like this:

```html
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="polciynumber" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Please Enter Policy Number:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4 ui-widget">
      <input id="endtpolnumber" type="text" class="form-control col-sm-1" name="endtpolnumber" placeholder="Plase Enter Policy Number">
      <button type="button" id="findpolinfo" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-3">Find Policy</button>
    </div>
    <label for="insuredsname" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Department:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="endtdept" name="endtdept" placeholder="" disabled="disabled">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="addendt">Add Endorsement</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="addendtclearform">Clear Form</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```