# Form data not getting submitted on Button Click to PHP File

Tags: php, html

I'm using the following code to do a simple login in php.I have set an action to `test.php` but nothing happens when the login button is clicked.

```
    <div class="limiter">
        <div class="container-login100" style="background-image: url('images/bg-01.jpg');">
            <div class="wrap-login100">
                <form class="login100-form validate-form" action="test.php">
                    <span class="login100-form-logo">
                        <i class="zmdi zmdi-landscape"></i>
                    </span>

                    <span class="login100-form-title p-b-34 p-t-27">
                        Log in
                    </span>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate = "Enter username">
                        <input class="input100" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xf207;"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="Enter password">
                        <input class="input100" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password">
                        <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xf191;"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="contact100-form-checkbox">
                        <input class="input-checkbox100" id="ckb1" type="checkbox" name="remember-me">
                        <label class="label-checkbox100" for="ckb1">
                            Remember me
                        </label>
                    </div>

                    <div class="container-login100-form-btn">
                        <button class="login100-form-btn">
                            Login
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-center p-t-90">
                        <a class="txt1" href="#">
                            Forgot Password?
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: change `<button class="login100-form-btn">Login</button>` to `<button class="login100-form-btn" type="submit">Login</button>`

Comment: give button type `submit`. and form method you have not set so manage accordingly because default is GET.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra default form method is GET. so it's always set

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile yes default is get, so i jst inform to use $_GET

Comment: You should also post the contents of the `test.php` file as well

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I thought that but according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4667979) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) the default for a button is submit if its inside a form! Go figure

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile That fixed the issue :) Thanks

Comment: @RiggsFolly no i'm refering to form method. The OP form does not have a method attribute therefore default  is GET?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Ok, just read your first comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<button class="login100-form-btn">Login</button>
```

To

```
<button class="login100-form-btn" type="submit">Login</button>
```

And also add a method attribute to your form.

`<form class="login100-form validate-form" action="test.php">`

to look

`<form class="login100-form validate-form" action="test.php" method="POST">`

Then on your test.php side use `$_POST`

Comment: Adding `type="submit"` is not necessary. "Submit" is the default type for a button inside a form where the attribute is not specified. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button). And here's a demo of the OP's original code: https://jsfiddle.net/agjcyz0L/ You can see that clicking the Login button causes the form to submit, without the "type" attribute being needed. If OP is saying that nothing is happening, then possibly they have some other issue. Either that or they are not describing the problem very clearly.